# How to boot an USB without acces to the BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios

I've got here a laptop which has the BIOS protected by a password. I neither can't sign in any user from the system (Windows 10).

How can I boot an USB with a Windows 10 iso and reinstall the system?

Comment: In general that is “enterprise” protection designed to prevent both the designated user as well as malicious users and thieves from installing unauthorized software and/or bypassing access restrictions. Usually your IT department will have an override password for when they need to reinstall the laptop. Bring it them.

Comment: @Bob in my case this isnt about any "enterprise", this is just a laptop one friend gave me to unlock it, he said that its owner failed.

Comment: Pull the disk from the computer, and remove all partitions, if USB boot is enabled at all it will now be tried as second option. If not then you could try to create a partition on the disk and copy over the data from usb. (It only needs to have boot and sources/boot.wim)

Answer (score 3):

Password protection for BIOS exists for a reason.
And its used to prevent hostile take over of a PC.

There is a chance you can reset the BIOS using the hardware pins. You can find that in your Motherboard user guide.

The above is a harder process for laptops if it exists at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been told not to touch any hardware. And im a 100% sure there's a way to boot an USB without needing any BIOS password.

Comment: In that case they must have enabled the 'Boot through USB first' option by default in your BIOS. You should be able to create a bootable USB through rufus https://rufus.ie/en/ and try and install from that by rebooting.

Comment: I already have a bootable USB, however I still can't boot the USB. I guess the option that allows USB is disabled. I need a way to boot a USB without acces to the BIOS.

Comment: One last thing you could check is if the USB is showing up in Windows 10 advanced boot options. You'll be able to reboot to it from windows.

Comment: I already tried that, it wont show up, the USB boot as i said before, its disabled. Thx anyways. Someone told me that there's a way to force a USB boot, like, u have 2 turn the laptop on, off, on, and do it like several times, and suddenly the USB boots, but that didnt work for me. Maybe I am not sure if I'm following his tip properly, but something is wrong. HELP! :'(
BTW im not asking to because I want to do something Illegal, idk why ppl r unvoting the post.

Comment: Your intentions may be pure. But the question is in itself a grey area. Can't be avoided I guess.

Comment: Im not doing nothing illegal im telling you.

Comment: @XChikuX The only way I'm aware of to remove a laptop's UEFI firmware/BIOS passphrase is either via the OEM or having the UEFI firmware/BIOS chip on the motherboard unsoldered and a new one soldered on _(requires a microscopic soldering station electronics repair companies like UBreakIFix have)_

Answer (score 3):

If USB boot is disabled there is no way to boot from it without entering the bios.

If you don't have the bios password you have to contact the support of the manufacturer of the laptop, they should be able to help you. It might be necessary to provide proof that you actually own the laptop though. And be warned, with some laptop models there just is no way to reset the bios password and the only solution is to replace the mainboard.

Another option would be to put the hard disk into a different computer and reinstall it there. With Linux this is pretty easy, with Windows you should use a (nearly) identical model for that. This only works if the laptop hasn't been set up with secure boot though.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops will have a boot menu you can access wiithout having to go into the bios.

For example, HP Elitebooks will allow you to press F9 to access the boot menu.

It would help to know what model of laptop (you should be able to Google the hotkey to access the boot menu for this model).

Comment: That boot menu might also require the password though.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the "frugal install" option of unetbootin (source: https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes). You can then boot the iso file from the harddrive without even needing a USB port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

On laptops, if you need to reset bios, normally there are two tin solder under the black plastic under the ram!! Or disconnect the batteri(if possible, wise to take the batteri out anyway even if the two solder points are there!!) You have to remove the ram and the plastic under on one of the sides if more then one ram port..
Good luck..remember every bios have a way to reset it, but I know some laptop(bios) can be difficult..

Comment: Welcome to SU. This doesn't actually answer the question, as it depends very much on the laptop. Furthermore the password may not even be stored in the UEFI itself but on another chip that can't be resetted at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181812)